# Employees with higher salary than their department average?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a table called employees which i have name, department_id and salary in it. I want to find the employees whose salary is greater than the average of their department and see their names, department_id, salary and the average salary of their department. I have written this code but it does not work. How can we fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT name, department_id, salary, avg(salary)
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY name, department_id, salary
    HAVING salary > (select avg(salary) from employees group by department_id)
```

I have updated my code as you said like:

```
    SELECT department_id, salary, avg(salary), count(*)
    FROM employees e
    GROUP BY department_id, salary
    HAVING salary > (select avg(salary) from employees e2 where e2.department_id=e.department_id)
```

But when i run this i get this result:

[image: result]

You can see that salary and the averages are the same and there are 2 department 80's, i need 1 of all the existing departments. How can we fix this. I am using the Oracle database if that's any important. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Your code is quite close.  But, instead of a `group by` in the subquery, it needs to be *correlated* to the outer query.  And, you don't need an outer aggregation, just a `where` clause:

```
SELECT name, department_id, salary
FROM employees e
WHERE salary > (select avg(salary) from employees e2 where e2.department_id = e.department_id);
```

However, you are presumably learning Oracle.  You can also write this query using analytic functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, avg(salary) over (partition by department) as avgsalary
      from employees e
     ) e
where e.salary > e.avgsalary;
```

Although this is probably a bit advanced for what you are learning, I encourage you to understand both queries.

Comment: What do i have to do to print the average salaries of the department's too? Because the code gives me the salary but when i added avg(salary) or (select avg salary from employees group by department_id) it didn't work.

Comment: @Solijoli . . . All the more reason you should learn to use window functions.  The second query has this information.